# Querying across multiple aggregates with EF when following DDD

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, navigation-properties

We are trying to follow the principles of DDD whilst developing our a new application. EF2.1 is being used to persist the entities.

We have a number of scenarios where an entity with one aggregate may reference something in another aggregate. For example an Order my have a reference to a Customer. On the Order entity we are implementing this by holding the foreign key value. An over simplified model.

```
public class Order
{
    DateTime OrderDate {get; set;}
    int CustomerId {get; set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    int Id {get
    string Name {get; set;}
}
```

We don't include any navigation properties on the Order object to the Customer object as it blurs the boundaries of the aggregrate

For a requirement where we may need to list orders and include the name of the customer placing the order, the teams preference is to use EF and Linq to query the data and use Automapper to map to a Dto to return to the client app. Not having the navigation property makes it very difficult to include the related Customer to retrieve the Name.

Whilst EF is great for persisting the aggegrates using it for querying the data for read models can be complex if you don't have the navigation properties. Plain old SQL with something like Dapper in my opinion would be fair easier (and possibly more performant) for this type of read. The team are putting up a fight and don't want to use SQL. This has lead to either navigation properties being added in some cases or very complex linq queries over the entities.

Does anyone have any strong views on the approach that should be taken for creating read models?

Comment: A good article on the topic: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/mt842503.aspx

Comment: Why are you not hooking up navigation?  Having navigation sets up potential foreign keys to prevent orphaned records, using 'Includes(x => x.object)' to not have repeat calls to the database, as well as having a larger object to play with.  You can choose to use 'include' or not to lessen scope.  But doing a thing like 'ctx.orders.toList()' then 'ctx.People.toList()' or similar and then doing everything in C# you are hitting the database with repeat calls and getting rid of one of the best benefits of EF IMHO.

Comment: I tend to use duplicate classes and map them to the various contexts. In this case there could be a little `OrderCustomer` class that contains just the right amount of properties to serve purposes of the Order aggregate.

Comment: @djangojazz many of the examples around DDD and aggregate design discourage against holding references to other aggregate and should only be the foreign keys. I admit there has to be a certain amount of pragmatism and in this case it would purely for the benefit of ease of building the read query.

Comment: @stuartmanton To be honest I must have not read enough on DDD of the way you are doing it.  I always thought the concept was to be isolated blocks of work that serve a single purpose.  I always took that to not have cluttered models but you could still have navigation.  If you are having foreign keys that can be publicly set and are doing the manual creation I am not seeing the benefit of that so I would be curious to read a paper on why that would be attempted.  In the example that Steve Greene gave Julie Lerman doesn't seem to get away from navigations but is more on value types.

Comment: I would also add you can have a property that directly exposes your graphing to the child objects and do a many to many transformation as well.  This happens on the OnModelCreating on the DataContext.  This is not persisting the data till you tell the contextual operation you want it.  So when doing something like context.person.Include("PersonOrders.Order").  I am really saying: "Join from Person table to bridge table that holds ints of keys mapping Person to Order in a many to many to the order table to get order detail"  It's essentially one SQL query and persisted only when you tell it to.

Answer (score -1):

> an Order my have a reference to a Customer. On the Order entity we are implementing this by holding the foreign key value.
>
> list orders and include the name of the customer placing the order

Then you need to get the `Customer` using the `Order.CustomerId`

```
using(var ctx = new Context())
{
    var orderWithCustomerName = ctx
        .Order
        .Select(o => new OrderWithCustomerName
        {
            Order = o,
            Customer = ctx.Customer.First(c => c.Id == o.CustomerId)
        })
        .ToList();
}
```